# Create HMAC value of a response payload for GST API

Tags: c#, hmac

As per website, GST API needs its response payload to be HMAC with the session Key provided. But the issue is how? Here is what I tried and which is wrong :

```
public static string GetHMAC(string requestPayload, string sessionKey){
     HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256( sessionKey );
     byte[]  responsePayload = hmac.ComputeHash(Convert.FromBase64String( requestPayload )
     return Convert.ToBase64String( responsePayload );
}
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: I get response code of error with message "incorrect response payload"

Comment: When asking questions on SO, it's best to provide more information.  For example, I'm guessing that *GST* is the Canadian *Goods and Services Tax*, but I'm not sure.  Mentioning it might fire off some associations in one of your readers' heads.  It looks like you are getting a compiler error (given @VilsadPP's answer).  Say so, and say what the error number and text are.  Don't just say "which is wrong".  The more info that you give your readers, the more likely you are to get a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

you need to convert your secret key to byte array before passing to the constructor. Please check the below code

```
public static string GetHMAC(string requestPayload, string sessionKey){
    byte[] key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sessionKey);
    HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256( key );
    byte[]  responsePayload = hmac.ComputeHash(Convert.FromBase64String( requestPayload )
    return Convert.ToBase64String( responsePayload );
}
```

Comment: I guess its exactly correct. And your code will actually give a compilation error. Rather let me suggest a better way to solve it

Comment: whats the error you are getting, also share how you are implimenting this

Comment: "incorrect response payload" , I assume incorrect request payload. which means there is some issue with your post data, I hope you are not getting the session key as base64 encoded, then instead of converting string to bytes, you need to base64 decode the key. you can also check the result by using an online tool to generate the HMAC using the same key and same payload. if these match then its an API related issue, you will have to contact the provider